Unable to communicate kafka broker containers in docker environment
In my development environment, I just tried to set up SASL SSL communication between producer, consumer apps, and 3 kafka brokers as dockerized. Self signed certificates created with below commands in WSL 2 Ubuntu distro. By the way, my host machine OS is Windows 11.
> sudo openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out ca-key.pem -aes256
> sudo openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key ca-key.pem -sha256 -days 365 -out ca-cert.pem -subj "/CN=KafkaCA"
> sudo keytool -genkey -noprompt -alias kafka1 -dname "CN=kafka1" -keystore kafka.keystore.jks -keyalg RSA -storepass pass123* -keypass pass123*
> sudo keytool -keystore kafka.keystore.jks -alias kafka1 -certreq -file kafka1.csr -storepass pass123* -keypass pass123*
> sudo openssl x509 -req -in kafka1.csr -CA ca-cert.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -CAcreateserial -out kafka1-cert.pem -days 365 -sha256 -passin pass:pass123*
> sudo keytool -keystore kafka.keystore.jks -alias CARoot -import -file ca-cert.pem -storepass pass123* -keypass pass123* -noprompt
> sudo keytool -keystore kafka.truststore.jks -alias CARoot -import -file ca-cert.pem -storepass pass123* -keypass pass123* -noprompt
> sudo keytool -keystore kafka.keystore.jks -alias kafka1 -import -file kafka1-cert.pem -storepass pass123* -keypass pass123* -noprompt

Also, kafka_server_jaas.conf and zookeeper_jaas.conf files are configured below.

kafka_server_jaas.conf:
KafkaServer {
   org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
   username="admin"
   password="admin-secret"
   user_admin="admin-secret"
   user_user1="user1-secret";
};

Client {
   org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required
   username="zookeeper"
   password="zookeeper-secret";
};

zookeeper_jaas.conf:
Client {
    org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required
    username="zookeeper"
    password="zookeeper-secret";
};


These configuration files are created manually because of permission issues and copied to containers via docker compose file and there is no problem with it. The below configuration is my docker-compose file. I had connection issues when running kafka broker docker containers, so I commented out the other 2 broker configurations. I just tried it with only one broker setup. Containers are running but I'm getting error logs (written after docker compose configuration) below. I cannot figure it out, I tried too many configurations but nothing changed. By the way I do not have enough experience for Kafka & Docker.
    zookeeper:
    container_name: zookeeper
    image: bitnami/zookeeper:latest 
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    volumes:
      - zookeeper_data:/bitnami1
      - \\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\secrets\zookeeper_jaas.conf:/opt/bitnami/kafka/config/zookeeper_jaas.conf
    environment:
      - ZOO_ENABLE_AUTH=yes
      - ZOO_SERVER_ID=1
      - ZOO_SERVERS=0.0.0.0:2888:3888
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=no
      - ZOO_SERVER_JVMFLAGS=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/opt/bitnami/kafka/config/zookeeper_jaas.conf
      - ZOO_SERVER_USERS=zookeeper
      - ZOO_SERVER_PASSWORDS=zookeeper-secret
      - ZOO_CLIENT_USER=zookeeper
      - ZOO_CLIENT_PASSWORD=zookeeper-secret
    networks:
      - kafka-net1
  kafka1: 
    image: bitnami/kafka:latest
    container_name: kafka1
    environment:
      - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL
      - KAFKA_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092,SASL_SSL://0.0.0.0:9093
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka1:9092,SASL_SSL://kafka1:9093
      - KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=SASL_SSL
      - KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_FILENAME=kafka.keystore.jks
      - KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_CREDENTIALS=kafka-ssl-credentials
      - KAFKA_SSL_KEY_PASSWORD=pass123*
      - KAFKA_CFG_SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=pass123*
      - KAFKA_CFG_SSL_KEY_PASSWORD=pass123*
      - KAFKA_CFG_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD=pass123*
      - KAFKA_CFG_SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION=/opt/bitnami/kafka/config/certs/kafka.keystore.jks
      - KAFKA_CFG_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION=/opt/bitnami/kafka/config/certs/kafka.truststore.jks
      - KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_FILENAME=kafka.truststore.jks
      - KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_CREDENTIALS=kafka-ssl-credentials
      - KAFKA_SECURITY_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL=SASL_SSL
      - KAFKA_CFG_SASL_MECHANISM_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL=PLAIN
      - KAFKA_SASL_ENABLED_MECHANISMS=PLAIN
      - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_SASL_CLIENT=true
      - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_SASL_CLIENTCONFIG=Client
      - KAFKA_OPTS=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/opt/bitnami/kafka/config/kafka_server_jaas.conf
    volumes:
      - \\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\secrets\kafka.keystore.jks:/opt/bitnami/kafka/config/certs/kafka.keystore.jks
      - \\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\secrets\kafka.truststore.jks:/opt/bitnami/kafka/config/certs/kafka.truststore.jks
      - \\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\secrets\kafka_server_jaas.conf:/opt/bitnami/kafka/config/kafka_server_jaas.conf
    ports:
      - "9093:9093" 
      - "9092:9092" 
    networks:
      - kafka-net1
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
  # kafka2:
  #   image: bitnami/kafka:latest
  #   environment:
  #     - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=2
  #     - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
  #     - KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL
  #     - KAFKA_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9094,SASL_SSL://localhost:9095
  #     - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka2:9094,SASL_SSL://kafka2:9095
  #     - KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=SASL_SSL
  #     - KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_FILENAME=kafka.keystore.jks
  #     - KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_CREDENTIALS=kafka-ssl-credentials
  #     - KAFKA_SSL_KEY_PASSWORD=pass123*
  #     - KAFKA_CFG_SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=pass123*
  #     - KAFKA_CFG_SSL_KEY_PASSWORD=pass123*
  #     - KAFKA_CFG_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD=pass123*
  #     - KAFKA_CFG_SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION=/opt/bitnami/kafka/config/certs/kafka.keystore.jks
  #     - KAFKA_CFG_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION=/opt/bitnami/kafka/config/certs/kafka.truststore.jks
  #     - KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_FILENAME=kafka.truststore.jks
  #     - KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_CREDENTIALS=kafka-ssl-credentials
  #     - KAFKA_SECURITY_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL=SASL_SSL
  #     - KAFKA_CFG_SASL_MECHANISM_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL=PLAIN
  #     - KAFKA_SASL_ENABLED_MECHANISMS=PLAIN
  #     - KAFKA_OPTS=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/opt/bitnami/kafka/config/kafka_server_jaas.conf
  #   volumes:
  #     - \\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\secrets\kafka.broker2.keystore.jks:/opt/bitnami/kafka/config/certs/kafka.keystore.jks
  #     - \\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\secrets\kafka.broker2.truststore.jks:/opt/bitnami/kafka/config/certs/kafka.truststore.jks
  #     - \\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\secrets\kafka_server_jaas_broker2.conf:/opt/bitnami/kafka/config/kafka_server_jaas.conf
  #   ports:
  #     - "9094:9094" 
  #   networks:
  #     - kafka-net
  # kafka3:
  #   image: bitnami/kafka:latest
  #   environment:
  #     - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=3
  #     - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
  #     - KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=INSIDE:SASL_SSL,OUTSIDE:SASL_SSL
  #     - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=INSIDE://kafka3:9092,OUTSIDE://kafka3:9095
  #     - KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=INSIDE
  #     - KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_FILENAME=kafka.keystore.jks
  #     - KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_CREDENTIALS=kafka-ssl-credentials
  #     - KAFKA_SSL_KEY_PASSWORD=pass123*
  #     - KAFKA_CFG_SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=pass123*
  #     - KAFKA_CFG_SSL_KEY_PASSWORD=pass123*
  #     - KAFKA_CFG_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD=pass123*
  #     - KAFKA_CFG_SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION=/opt/bitnami/kafka/config/certs/kafka.keystore.jks
  #     - KAFKA_CFG_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION=/opt/bitnami/kafka/config/certs/kafka.truststore.jks
  #     - KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_FILENAME=kafka.truststore.jks
  #     - KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_CREDENTIALS=kafka-ssl-credentials
  #     - KAFKA_SECURITY_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL=SASL_SSL
  #     - KAFKA_CFG_SASL_MECHANISM_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL=PLAIN
  #     - KAFKA_SASL_ENABLED_MECHANISMS=PLAIN
  #     - KAFKA_OPTS=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/opt/bitnami/kafka/config/kafka_server_jaas.conf
  #   volumes:
  #     - \\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\secrets\kafka.broker3.keystore.jks:/opt/bitnami/kafka/config/certs/kafka.keystore.jks
  #     - \\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\secrets\kafka.broker3.truststore.jks:/opt/bitnami/kafka/config/certs/kafka.truststore.jks
  #     - \\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\secrets\kafka_server_jaas_broker3.conf:/opt/bitnami/kafka/config/kafka_server_jaas.conf
  #   ports:
  #     - "9095:9095" 
  #   networks:
  #     - kafka-net
  kafka-ui:
    container_name: kafka-ui
    image: provectuslabs/kafka-ui:latest
    ports:
      - 9100:8080
    environment:
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_NAME: local
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS: kafka1:9092 #, kafka2:9093, kafka3:9094
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_ZOOKEEPER: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_JMXPORT: 9997
    depends_on:
      - kafka1
      #- kafka2
      #- kafka3
volumes:
  local_pgdata:
  pgadmin-data:
  es-data: 
  redis-data:
  zookeeper_data:
  kafka_data1:
  # kafka_data2:
  # kafka_data3:
networks:
  es-net:
    driver: bridge
  kafka-net1:
    driver : bridge


Error Logs in kafka broker container:
    2024-08-23 15:59:17 [2024-08-23 12:59:17,741] WARN [RequestSendThread controllerId=1] Controller 1's connection to broker kafka1:9093 (id: 1 rack: null) was unsuccessful (kafka.controller.RequestSendThread)
2024-08-23 15:59:17 java.io.IOException: Connection to kafka1:9093 (id: 1 rack: null) failed.
2024-08-23 15:59:17     at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClientUtils.awaitReady(NetworkClientUtils.java:71)
2024-08-23 15:59:17     at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.brokerReady(ControllerChannelManager.scala:299)
2024-08-23 15:59:17     at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.doWork(ControllerChannelManager.scala:252)
2024-08-23 15:59:17     at org.apache.kafka.server.util.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.java:135)


Btw, Kafka doesn't require Zookeeper anymore. That can simplify your setup

@OneCricketeer, I didn't know, will try. Thank you

@OneCricketeer, removed Zookeeper config, rerun containers but nothing changed. Thanks anyway

I just said Zookeeper wasn't required. It wasn't a solution to the SSL config. You're missing Kraft mode environment variables on the broker, anyway. Feel free to [edit] your question with your latest changes
